# Infinite loop not checking for string size and belonging to alphabet

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop, alphabet

I've been trying to make a check for if the input (guesses) belongs to the alphabet and if it's a single character for my simple hangman game, but when I try to run the program it just ignores the entire if sentence. It's been working everywhere else and I just can't find the source of the problem.
Here is my code:

```
def eng():
    letter_list = []
    global word
    global letter
    g = 0
    lives = 10
    while True:
        word = input("Insert The Word: ")
        if not word.isalpha():
            print("Only letters of the English alphabet are allowed")
        else:
            print(letter)
            break
    cls = lambda: print('\n' * 256)
    cls()
    ready_letters = list(set(word.lower()))
    while True:
        q = len(ready_letters)
        print(q)
        while True:
            letter = input("Your guess: ")
            if not letter.isalpha() and len(letter) != 1:
                print("You can make a guess with only one letter of the English alphabet")
            else:
                break
        print(letter_list)
        if letter in ready_letters and letter not in letter_list:
            letter_list += letter
            print("Nice")
            g += 1
            if g == q:
                print(f"The word was: {word}")
                print("GG, ")
                print("\n")
                return
            print(f"{g}/{q} letters guessed correctly!")
        elif letter in letter_list:
            print("You already wrote this letter, try again")
        else:
            letter_list += letter
            print("Oh noie")
            lives -= 1
            print(f"You have {lives} lives left")
            if lives == 0:
                print("GG, 웃")
                return
```

(read comment)

General tips not related to the issue would also be appreciated.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why don't you print out `letter` before breaking to see if it's indeed alphabet? (If that's the problem cuz I'm not sure I understand your question). Also the indentation after `def eng():` doesn't seem to be valid?

Comment: It gives out an error when I try printing it before breaking the loop: NameError: name 'letter' is not defined

Comment: @MMZK1526 Sorry for the lack spaces, it works I guess, I'm a begginer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `word`, not `letter`. But according to my test, if you typed in non-alphabetical word, the `if` is triggered, so I don't think there's any problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mistake, instead of using `and` you should be using `or`. You want to print our your error message if they type a non-alpha character OR they type more than one letter.